# $\lim_{x\to a}$ and extension by definition

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I want to introduce function symbols $\lim_{x\to a}$ in the first-order language.

First, we introduce limit as a function symbol $fun$ for the sake of simplicity. $\forall f, a\exists! b\psi(b, f, a)$ is true as $\psi(b, f, a) = [f$ is real function] $\land\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ [$0 < | x − a | < \delta \to | f(x) − b | < \epsilon
]$, so by "extension by definition" we can have introduced the function symbol $fun$ in the language.
However $fun$ is one, but $\lim_{x\to a}$ is multiple and $\lim_{x\to a}$ have "argument $a$".

How can the symbols $\lim_{x\to a}$ be introduced?

Comment: "in the first-order language", but you haven't told us *which* language. Ordered sets? Ordered fields? Set theory? Arithmetic?

Comment: When you start talking about quantifying over functions, and defining functionals (your lim operator), this strongly suggests not first-order but a higher-order logic, at least 3rd. You *can* try to fake it with a multi-sorted first-order language, but you'll find the "user experience" unpleasant and the range of models will be broader than you intend.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have thought that lim would be added to the language of set theory, as well as the φ (i.e. the empty set).

Comment: @BrianO The "f" is a free variable, not a function symbol, and is designated as a real function (a set of ordered pair) in the formula $\psi$. Do we still need higher-order logic?

Comment: The language of set theory only has $\in$, there are no reals, there is no $<$, and there's no absolute value. We can add all these things, but since the reals are just an object, all of this is just a first-order definition (up to fixing a set to model the real numbers, etc.), in which case the limit operator is just another set, being a partial function from $\Bbb{R^R\times R}$, mapping $(f,a)$ to $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ if it exists. But it is just a set, it's an object in the universe.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree with you. I don't write "the language of set theory," it should have said "extended the language of set theory"(i.e. necessary function symbols and predicate symbols have been added). φ is indeed a set, but "φ" as a string is not a set, it's just a symbol, right? What I want to know is: How are strings "$lim_{x\to a}$"　added in extended the language of set theory. "Unlike "φ", $lim_{x\to a}$ has "argument", so I think it feels difficult.

Comment: $f$ is not free in $\forall f, a \exists! b \psi(f, a, b)$.

Comment: @BrianO Sorry, I made a mistake. The "f" is a variable, not a function symbol, and is designated as a real function (a set of ordered pair) in the formula $\psi$.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me that you were working in the first-order language of set theory, ZF. Now I see what you're asking. Your definition of $\psi$ has incorrect quantifier order for what you're trying to express: it asserts a kind of uniformity that few $f$ enjoy. I *think* you want it to say "$f$ has limit $b$ at $a$. It is not the case that for all $f, a$ there's a $b$ for which that's true. "$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$" should be outermost, certainly it should precede "$\exists\delta > 0$".
<cont>

Comment: ... "$f$ is a real function" should ideally be outside all three quantifiers.
These small problems aside, as @AsafKaragila says above, your proposed lim(f, a) operator is just a set, a definable partial function of a certain type which you can introduce a symbol for. Do you need more specifics about the definition?

Comment: @BrianO My point is as you wrote, "$f$ has limit $b$ at $a$." "$f$ is a real function" has been fixed. However, the location of $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ is exactly the same as wikipedia(i.e. [(ε, δ)-definition of limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_for_real_valued_functions)).

Comment: @BrianO I can understand that φ is added by "extensinon by definition." However, I can't understand the case where the symbol itself has an argument. If you can give us more specifics about the definition, please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let $\varphi(a, f, b)$ be a formula saying that $a$ is a real, $f$ is a real function and $b$ is a real that is **a** limit of $f$ at $a$:

$$\begin{align}
\varphi(a, f, b) \triangleq \ & f \colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} \  \land a\in\mathbb{R} \land b\in\mathbb{R} \ \land \\
&(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})\ 
[0 < | x − a | < \delta \Rightarrow | f(x) − b | < \epsilon
].
\end{align}
$$
Here we assume that $u > 0$ implies that $u\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now let $\psi(a, f, y)$ say that either $\varphi(a, f, b)$ holds, or $b = \emptyset$ and there is no $y$ for which $\varphi(a, f, y)$ holds:

$$\begin{align}
\psi(a, f, b) \triangleq & \ \varphi(a, f, b) \lor [\neg\ (\exists y)\ \varphi(a, f, y) \land b = \emptyset]
\end{align}$$
The second clause handles the cases where one or more variables is of the wrong type, or no limit exists.

I'll assume we're working in ZFC, though ZF + DC (Dependent Choice) would suffice. Consider the following set comprehension:

$$
L = \{(a, F)\mid a\in\mathbb{R} \land F \colon \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}\to \mathbb{R} \land (\forall f\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})\  \psi(a, f, F(f))
\} \tag{*}
$$

It's a theorem of ZFC that $L$ exists (is a set), $L$ is a function, and that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a unique F such that $(a, F)\in L$.

Finally, let $\theta(a, F)$ say that either $(a, F)\in L$, or $a\notin \mathbb{R}$ and $F = \emptyset$. Then it's a theorem of ZFC that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ there's a unique $F$ such that $\theta(a, F)$:
$$
\operatorname{ZFC}\vdash (\forall a)(\exists! F)\ \theta(a, F)
$$
This entitles us to introduce $\operatorname{lim}$ by definition, with the defining axiom:
$$
(\forall a)\ \theta(a, \operatorname{lim}(a))
$$
If $a\notin\mathbb{R}$, then $\operatorname{lim}(a) = \emptyset$, and if $a\in\mathbb{R}$, then for any real function $f$,

$$
\operatorname{lim}(a)(f) = 
\begin{cases}
\text{limit of } f \text{ at }a,  & \text{if the limit exists;} \\ 
\emptyset, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

You're free to write "$\operatorname{lim}_{x\to a}$" for $\operatorname{lim}(a)$, and by abuse of notation "$\operatorname{lim}_{x\to a}f(x)$" instead of $\operatorname{lim}_{x\to a}(f)$. The dummy variable $x$ serves no great purpose in this example, but it's clearly helpful with functions of more than one variable — for example,
$\operatorname{lim}_{u\to a}g(u, v)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I learned about extension by definitions from wikipedia, but I didn't realize that the limit symbol was so difficult to added in the language.

Comment: You're welcome. (You can thank me properly by accepting it as a correct answer to your question, and/or upvoting the answer.) I tried to show the details, and not be handwavy. About the same amount of work would be required to add a $\operatorname{min}$ symbol for real functions. (*Exercise*: work out the details for $\operatorname{min}$.)

Comment: I upvoted and accepted. But my reputation is less than 15, so It didn't reflect what I upvoted. It's very interesting how hard it is formally to introduce a familiar symbol like limitation. In order to learn that, I would like to try Exercise. Thanks again.